# What is the difference of closing for duplicate and flagging for duplicate?

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

When I encounter a duplicate, I have two choices: Vote closing because it is a duplicate, or flag it as a duplicate. What is the difference and should I do both?

Comment: You cannot do both, but they both do the same thing if you have the VTC privilege.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no difference - just two ways to get to the same thing.

Both end up being close as duplicate votes.

So long as you have the [cast close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) privilege.

---

If you do not have this privilege, you cannot close questions and can only flag them (assuming you have the [flag posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) privilege), in which case the vote is for a "recommend close", which does not contribute to the closure of the question (but does help with putting it the review queues).